# Is the value specified in OFFSET the same as rowid (sqlite)？

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization, cursor-position

I need a simple scrolling function for my sqlite table, returning the previous X records or the next X records from the last time I selected. As the rule #2 ["Do not try to implement a scrolling window using LIMIT and OFFSET"](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor) said here, I change to sql from

```
SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE xxx  LIMIT 5 OFFSET :index
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE xxx  and rowid > :index LIMIT 5
```

I do some simple test and the result seems to the same, eg. **select rowid from tracks where rowid > 100 limit 5** and **select rowid from tracks limit 5 offset 100** both return the same 5 records after rowid 100.

So my question is <1> is the value specified in OFFSET the same as rowid (assume I did not delete record)? <2> Did my change better ？

**Update**, I know when delete record, rowid may change. So my question is assuming I did not delete record, is the value used in OFFSET the same as rowid ? If not, what exactly does that value mean? And if I do delete some record, what exactly does that value means ?

Also, the article there said "This information is obsolete" but I just can't find the updated information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have deleted some rows, the `rowid` number are not longer the same as the index.

To show the rows for the next page, you should not use an `index` value, but the last value of the column that you're sorting by from the last page.

Comment: So for the value used in OFFSET, what is it exactly ? I also update my question.

Comment: OFFSET just counts rows. The `rowid` is a unique number, which is not always the same as the row number.

Comment: Do you mean when if I specify limit 5 offset 100,  sqlite has to iterate the first 100 records in order to get the next 5 records I need? And that is why it is low efficient ?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.